# Open a new WPF View as single window

Tags: wpf, .net-core, mvvm, mvvmcross

I am (trying to use /) using MVVMCross and would like to open by clicking on a button a new separated WPF window, which does not have to interact with the MainWindow. In PowerShell I could easily use:

```
    $window_mw = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse($xamlmw)
    $window_mw.Owner = $window
    $window_mw.ShowDialog()
```

I tried now the navigationService but this just replaces the current window:

```
using MvvmCross.Navigation;
_navigationService.Navigate<SecondViewModel>();
```

Is there a way to open just a new window? Or does it make sense to use the navigationService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look a the [ModalView](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bdaa09299714d94cf3f2c548a465d994c20d52f0/Projects/Playground/Playground.Wpf/Views/ModalView.xaml.cs) in the playground project:

```
[MvxWindowPresentation(Identifier = nameof(ModalView), Modal = true)]
public partial class ModalView 
{
    public ModalView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

You should have a similar `SecondView`. The sample `ModalViewModel` is implemented like [this](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/87a545a2f59eafd2179fdde29fcebef68f171656/Projects/Playground/Playground.Core/ViewModels/Navigation/ModalViewModel.cs).

Comment: Thanks! After tying the playground example I just had to change the dependencies and it could been ran. I took me a while but now I can the window like I wanted. But I have to admit, for someone who is just doing it in his free time, the code is hard to read without any comments.